# How to open excel workbook which needs login in vb?

Tags: vba, excel

I created an excel1 which has a login function (I've the username and password):

Pic: showing login window. (but I can't post the pic here because I don't have 10 reputation...)

Now I have another excel2 which need to read some information from excel1, and I want this can be done by just click a button, so I use vb.

But how to sent username&password to excel1 and open excel1 in background(I don't want the open process showing on screen).

Thanks

Add more description of my "login" window:

I insert an VBA Userform as the login window, it includes:

```
1, username_box: user can input login name here

2, pw_box: user can input password here

3, login_button: if click this button, sub login_button_Click() will be triggered

4, quit_button: if click this button, login will be cancelled
```

Private Sub login_button_Click()

```
Dim login_flag As Boolean
login_flag = False
'there is a sheet "users" which recorded the username and its password
For r = 2 To 100 Step 1
    If username_box.Text = Sheets("users").Cells(r, 1).Value And pw_box.Text = Sheets("users").Cells(r, 2).Value Then
        login_flag = True
        Application.Visible = True
        login_window.Hide
        pw_box = ""
    End If
Next r

If login_flag = False Then
    MsgBox "Input wrong"
    pw_box = ""
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: you can add link to your pic

Comment: You can share your function to log on? it will be easier to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

a lot depends on how the login to excel1.

If you use `Workbook_Open` Event to call `UserForm` where user fills login details, you can disable them `Application.EnableEvents = False`, example:

```
Sub OpenWb()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim WbSource As Workbook
Dim WbDest As Workbook
Dim ActWindow As String

Set WbDest = ActiveWorkbook

Application.EnableEvents = False

FilePath = "C:\tmp\excel1.xlsm" 'excel with password

Set WbSource = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

ActWindow = ActiveWorkbook.Name

ActiveWindow.Visible = False

WbDest.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = WbSource.Sheets(2).Cells(2, 2)

Application.EnableEvents = True
Windows(ActWindow).Visible = True
WbSource.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

If you want read some information so that user dont see you can set the visibility to false:
`ActiveWindow.Visible = False`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added my login function in the question.

Comment: @kknd12: if you open excel1 using `Set WbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\tmp\excel1.xlsm")` UserForm should not appear and you dont need pass login and password. UserForm will appear if you have in excel1 `Workbook_Open()` event where you use `UserForm1.Show`. Then you can use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to disable `Workbook_Open()`

Comment: Hi Dawid, thanks, your method is working. I'm new to vba, so my "login" system is easily bypassed by Application.EnableEvents = True? Is there any security way to login the excel?

Comment: @kknd12: I think the safest is to use a password to a excel file. However, there is no login, only password

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand your problem might be.

When you open a excel workbook as intance, the userform wont show up. If it is data transfer you talking about, then you can easily do it without triggering the workbook.open module.